# Angular-CLI proxy to backend for WebSocket

Tags: angular, angular-cli

It's perfectly working for Http, but not for WebSocket. I did not find the documentation about this. How can I do proxy for WS?

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

proxy.conf.json:

```
{
  "/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using ws:// instead of http://?

Comment: Yes, I tried. It also does not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Angular cli uses `http-proxy-middleware` for proxy under the hood. take a look at the documentation: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware

there is a websocket `ws` boolean option you can use as described in this section:
https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#http-proxy-options

so you can change your config to:

```
{
  "/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "ws":true
  }
}
```